# Notification actions in swiftui

Tags: swiftui

Actually I have tried the notification actions are working fine, but when the App is in foreground and notification appears, I need to drag down the notification to see the actions.
Is it possible to see the actions when tap on the notification?

func scheduleNotification6() {

```
     let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
     content.title = "How did you sleep?"
     content.subtitle = "Tap to give feedback and make changes"
     content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
     content.categoryIdentifier = "ACTION6"
     // show this notification five seconds from now
     let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 10, repeats: false)

     // choose a random identifier
     let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
```

//actions

```
     let feedback3 = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "FEEDBACK6", title: "Feedback", options: .foreground)
     //let close = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "CLOSE", title: "Close", options: .destructive)

     let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "ACTION6", actions: [feedback3], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
     UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])
     // add our notification request
     UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
     //UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = delegate
     
     
 }
```